# Implementing a Better Grep Command

Tags: files-and-directories, text, searching, regular-expressions

In [Working With String Patterns](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html), Wolfram documentation  yields a simple `Grep` function:

```
Grep[file_, patt_] := 
 With[{data = Import[file, "Lines"]}, 
  Pick[Transpose[{Range[Length[data]], data}], 
   StringFreeQ[data, patt], False]]
```

However, the actual `grep` function is far more sophisticated than this. For example running `grep -nr -C 2 <pattern>` allows us to search for `<pattern>` recursively through a directory, showing 2 lines of context around each match. Wolfram should in principle be able to do this (and even far better than this, perhaps using datasets?).

**Concrete Question:** How can one use Wolfram to create a grep function that at least reproduces `grep -nr -C N <pattern>` functionality? (If it simply wraps the actual `grep` command that's fine).

Comment: I think the only way here is to call `grep` from WL. Rewriting all the functionality in WL would take a very long time.

Comment: Does every Mathematica system have access to grep (e.g. Windows)?

Answer (score 12):

*Mathematica* allows text searching using [regular expressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegularExpression.html) (based on the PCRE library). It would take some work to re-implement the whole `grep` functionality within *Mathematica*, but for your concrete example

> ```
> grep -nr -C 2 <pattern>
> ```

it is as easy as follows:

```
ClearAll[Grep]
Grep[files_List, patt_, c_Integer: 0, style : {__} : {Red, Bold}] := 
  Monitor[Do[Grep[files[[i]], patt, c, style], {i, Length[files]}], 
   ProgressIndicator[i, {1, Length[files]}]];
Grep::noopen = "Can't open \"``\".";
Grep[file_, patt_, c_Integer: 0, style : {__} : {Red, Bold}] := 
  Module[{lines, pos}, 
   Quiet[Check[lines = ReadList[file, "String"], 
     Return[Message[Grep::noopen, file], Module]], {ReadList::noopen, ReadList::stream}];
   pos = Flatten@Position[StringContainsQ[lines, patt], True];
   If[pos =!= {}, 
    Echo@Grid[Prepend[{#, 
          Column@StringReplace[lines[[Span[Max[# - c, 1], UpTo[# + c]]]], 
            str : patt :> 
             "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"" <> str <> "\"," <> 
              StringRiffle[ToString /@ style, ", "] <> "]\)"]} & /@ pos, 
        {file, SpanFromLeft}], Dividers -> All, Alignment -> Left]];];
```

where

- `file` or `files` is a file name/path or a list of them
- `patt` is a literal string, [`StringExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringExpression.html) or [`RegularExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegularExpression.html) pattern to search for
- `c` is number of additional lines of leading and trailing output context
- `style` is a `List` of styling directives to be applied to the matching text (I use here great solution by [halirutan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/187/halirutan) from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98603/280) answer); if you don't want to apply a style, put `{{}}` as the value for this option

For obtaining the complete listing of files in a directory and all its subdirectories at all levels one can use [`FileNames`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileNames.html) as `Select[FileNames[All, dir, Infinity], Not@*DirectoryQ]`. A very enlightening discussion of its usage for obtaining only specific filepaths can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57951/280).

### Examples

Find lines containing the word "Welfare" and display them with 1 surrounding line of leading and trailing context:

```
Grep[FindFile@"ExampleData/USConstitution.txt",
 WordBoundary ~~ "Welfare" ~~ WordBoundary, 1]
```

> [image: screenshot1]

Search for word "eye" in all files in a directory and all its subdirectories:

```
dir = FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory,
    "Documentation/English/System/ExamplePages"}];

files = Select[FileNames[All, dir, Infinity], Not@*DirectoryQ];

Grep[files, WordBoundary ~~ "eye" ~~ WordBoundary]
```

> (* during evaluation it displays `ProgressIndicator` *)
>
> [image: screenshot2]

Comment: This is great. Is there a way to highlight the searched word throughout the Grid (something that `grep` does in most terminals)?

Comment: @George Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 7):

## Update

As recommended in the comments by @b3m2a1, you can also use [`RunProcess`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RunProcess.html) as a simpler way to execute `grep`.  You need to supply the command as a list of the `command` plus the space delimited arguments and set the ProcessDirectory.  To do a recursive search for `NotebookDirectory` in notebook files enter the following:

```
cmd = "grep -RH \"NotebookDirectory\" --include=\"Int*.nb\" *";
RunProcess[{"bash", "-c", cmd}, "StandardOutput", 
 ProcessDirectory -> NotebookDirectory[]]
(* "Absorption/BakedSlider/InterphaseMassTransfer_slider.nb:   \
  RowBox[{\"NotebookDirectory\", \"[\", \"]\"}], \"]\"}], \";\"}], 

Absorption/BakedSlider/InterphaseMassTransfer_slider.nb:" *)
```

## Original Answer

Here is an example calling the system grep (using Cygwin and putting bash.exe in my path on Windows).  Remember to escape special characters.  The following does a recursive directory search on "NotebookDirectory" including Mathematica notebooks matching the pattern "Int*.nb".

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
file = CreateFile[];
Run["grep -RH \"NotebookDirectory\" --include=\"Int*.nb\" * >>" <> file];
FilePrint[file]
DeleteFile[file];

(*Absorption/BakedSlider/InterphaseMassTransfer_slider.nb:     RowBox[{"NotebookDirectory", "[", "]"}], "]"}], ";"}], 
Absorption/BakedSlider/InterphaseMassTransfer_slider.nb:     RowBox[{"NotebookDirectory", "[", "]"}], "]"}], ";"}], 
Absorption/BakedSlider/InterphaseMassTransfer_sliderb.nb:     RowBox[{"NotebookDirectory", "[", "]"}], "]"}], ";"}], 
Absorption/BakedSlider/InterphaseMassTransfer_sliderb.nb:     *)
```

Comment: You can call `RunProcess` and have it adjust the path automatically so you don't need to put it on there. That'll also return the actual string. This is how I implemented my hook into `Grep`.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thanks for the tip.  Do you mind if I update my answer with your suggestion?

Comment: I mind not in the slightest

Comment: Use `ProcessDirectory`. You don’t need to set the directory at all. Also can use `ProcessEnvironment` to set the path.

Comment: @b3m2a1 That is a much better way to do it.  I will edit the post.